# Store a condition as a variable. Javascript

Tags: javascript, boolean, eval

In javaScript, is there a way to store a condition in a variable and then evaluate that condition later on.

I know this can be done using `eval()`

```
var condition = "(foo == pie);"
alert( eval(condition) );
```

The value of the alert above will change depending on the values of `foo` & `pie`.

Is there a similar way to do this without using `eval()`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This really looks like what a **function** is :

```
var conditionChecker = function(){ return foo == pie };
alert( conditionChecker() );
```

Comment: haha! Its first thing in the morning. My brains not working yet. Damn. I. Feel. Stupid.

Answer (score 2):

Even simpler would be:

```
var conditionChecker = foo == pie;
alert( conditionChecker );
```